# Base url method in ci

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am working on a practice project on ci.but the base url method returns [::1]/project name/ instead of localhost/project name/, and it's happening only when another  function called. Otherwise it return localhost/project name/.
And when I configure the base url but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your base_url is empty.

In application/config/config.php

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_name';

Comment: There is no such file like app.php. in ci 3.1.11

Comment: In ci 3 go to application->config.php , There should be $config['base_url'] = ''; ,Fill it with your base url.  'h*ttp://localhost'

Comment: i have done it but it's not working